# Want to add a delay for textView when using livedata that pass LatLon

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-service, android-livedata

Are passing data between a service to a fragment using a MutableLiveData.
Accordenly to a Log.d statement the data is recived.
But when i try to use TextView to display the data i get null. It think a delay makes it null. Is there a way to delay or update the textview so i can display the data?

DashbordFragment.kt

```
class DashbordFragment : Fragment() {

private var locationList = mutableListOf<LatLng>()
var liveLatLng = MutableLiveData<LatLng>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    sendActionCommandToService(Constants.ACTION_SERVICE_START)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    observerTrackerService()
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashbord, container, false)
}
lateinit var binding : FragmentDashbordBinding
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding = FragmentDashbordBinding.bind(view)

    binding.btGotostation.setOnClickListener {

        startActivity(Intent(requireContext(),StationsActivity::class.java))
    }
    binding.btGotostatistics.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(DashbordFragmentDirections.actionDashbordFragmentToStatisticsFragment())
    }

    binding.btGotolinediagram.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(DashbordFragmentDirections.actionDashbordFragmentToLineDiagramFragment())
    }

    binding.btMap.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(DashbordFragmentDirections.actionDashbordFragmentToMapsFragment())
    }
    binding.latlon.text = liveLatLng.value.toString()


}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_menu, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun observerTrackerService(){
    TrackerService.locationList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

        if (it != null) {
            locationList = it
            Log.d("LocationList",locationList.toString())
        }
    }
    TrackerService.liveLatLng.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){

        Log.d("LiveLatLng", it.toString())
    }
    Log.d("LocationList", "Tester")

}
private fun sendActionCommandToService(action: String){
    Intent(
        requireContext(),
        TrackerService::class.java
    ).apply {
        this.action = action
        requireContext().startService(this)
    }
}
```

---

fragment_dashbord.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:text="@string/dashboard"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/go_to_station"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt_gotostation"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/GoogleMap"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/btMap"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/statistics_desc"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/development_bar_chart"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt_gotostatistics"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/development_line_diagram"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt_gotolinediagram"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latlon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/statistics_desc"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting this in `onViewCreated` which is called earlier than you received the data.
Instead you can set an observer as follows in `onViewCreated`
example :

```
liveLatLng.observe(this , Observer {
    it?.let{
        binding.latlon.text = it.toString()
    }
})
```

and set the value as follows

```
TrackerService.liveLatLng.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    liveLatLng.value = it // hoping this is of type LatLng
}
```

Note: Consider this according to android dev docs

> Make sure to store LiveData objects that update the UI in ViewModel
> objects, as opposed to an activity or fragment, for the following
> reasons: To avoid bloated activities and fragments. Now these UI
> controllers are responsible for displaying data but not holding data
> state. To decouple LiveData instances from specific activity or
> fragment instances and allow LiveData objects to survive configuration
> changes.

from [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#create_livedata_objects)

Answer (score 1):

This `binding.latlon.text = liveLatLng.value.toString()` has nothing in common with livedata. When used correctly, your code should look like this `binding.latlon = liveLatLng` and no need for delay, `LiveData` will do it for you. To reach this all you need is to check [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) and [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

Small hint for required binding variable

```
<import type="com.google.type.LatLng" />

<variable
    name="latlon"
    type="androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;LatLng&gt;" />
```